# Unit tests code duplication tests, how manage them

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd

Consider i am use TDD in a right way

I have a class **A** and **ATest** class for it. I need class **B** that is nearly the same as class **A**, and my decision is use abstract class - **Alphabet**, and move commons functions for **A** and **B** to that class. In that moment i have not tests for **Alphabet** abstract class because i properly tested all functions throught **A** class and lift up them to abstract, all good and works in TDD way. But in this moment i have tests that covers not only **A** part of functionality in **ATest** but also a **Alphabet** specific test cases, should i duplicate that cases in **B** class, **C, D** and etc.?

Where do i should put that test cases in yours opinion?

Comment: `I need class B that is nearly the same as class A` something wrong there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to your question: you implementing a concrete Testingclass that extends your **Alphabet**. With this Testingclass now you have the ability to write Tests, that tests explicit you abstractclass. **One hint:** Your concrete testingclass should only available in your test-packagestructure.

And for your other class like **A**, **B** etc, you can now writing tests, that tests explicit this implementation of **A**, **B** etc. and you don't have to test explicit the abstractclass anymore.

Best regards
Andree

Answer (score 0):

You should move the tests that cover functionality of `Alphabet` to `AlphabetTest` class and remove them from `ATest`.

I recommend that when you test `Alphabet`, you create a child and overrides all your abstract methods dummy functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Move the tests which cover the code of `Alphabet` in an abstract class `AlphabetTest`.

Now, `ATest`, `BTest` (and so on) have to extend `AlphabetTest`.

Run the tests and you will see that tests of `AlphabetTest` are executed for `ATest`, `BTest` (and so on)